# Why is it so hard to find a free downloadable chess database with older/historical chess games?

Tags: database

The best free, downloadable chess database I've found is Kingbase (http://www.kingbase-chess.net). It only has games since 1990. I also have the Android Chessbase Online app, which also appears to only have relatively newer games. The only source I know of that has historical chess games is www.chessgames.com (but I don't think you can download the entire database into something like SCID).

Why are these older games so hard to come by?

Comment: The Kingbase link no longer works -- another dead project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I invite you do it yourself...

> https://github.com/student-t/ExtractPGN

This is my Python repository for web crawling chess games. I use it to extract PGN chess games from Chessgames. This is an example of the games I extracted:

- http://smallchess.com/Games

It's trivial to change the code such that you extract all games from chessgames (**entire database**) into a single PGN file. I believe you're a programmer, so that shouldn't be an issue for you.

Comment: The github link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

This is the link for SmallChess's Python repository for web crawling chess games I found it, just click here : https://github.com/pmerg/ExtractPGN